# How to send data from view to controller action in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I developed a custom HtmlHelper extension method but that data is not
posting Action.

**HtmlHelper extension class:**

```
public static class TestHtmlHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString CreateControl(this HtmlHelper helper, string tagName, IDictionary<string, string> attributes)
    {
        var newTag = new TagBuilder(tagName);
        newTag.MergeAttributes(attributes, true);

        return  MvcHtmlString.Create(newTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }

    public static string Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string id, string url, string alternateText, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        // Create tag builder
        var builder = new TagBuilder("img");

        // Create valid id
        builder.GenerateId(id);

        // Add attributes
        builder.MergeAttribute("src", url);
        builder.MergeAttribute("alt", alternateText);
        builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));

        // Render tag
        return builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
    }

}
```

**//View code**

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Go","Home",FormMethod.Post))
{
    IDictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    d.Add("type", "text");
    d.Add("id", "text1");
    d.Add("required", "required");
    @Html.Raw(Html.CreateControl("input", d))
    @Html.Raw(Html.Image("image1", "/Images/bullet.png", "bullet", new { border = "4px" }))
    d = null;
    d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    d.Add("type", "submit");
    d.Add("value", "Go");
    @Html.Raw(Html.CreateControl("input", d))
    <span></span>
    d = null;
    d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    d.Add("value", "text");
    d.Add("id", "span1");
    d.Add("text", "required");
    @Html.Raw(Html.CreateControl("span", d))
}
```

**// Controller code**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Go(string test)
{
    return Content(test);
}
```

I didn't get data in string test. I want to submit that data to DB.

Comment: I do not see any input type with name = test in your form. To get the value on the action parameters, those inputs must have same name.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873098/html-asp-net-mvc-4-razor-get-textbox-input-value/18873263#18873263

Answer (score 3):

To get input values as parameters for an MVC action, you need to include **NAME** for the input types.

- I do not see **NAME** for any input types in your code.
- Also I do not see **TEST** in your code

For example, if your form is -

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit","Ajax",FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="text" name="Rami"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
}
```

Output ScreenShot -

[image]

Comment: This is a weird screenshot. I thought they have the VS Debugger inside of SO :-)

Comment: @MalcolmFrexner, hahaha :-) . Updated with a heading.

Answer (score 1):

Put your inputs inside a form tag. All the input data will be sent to the controller on form submit. Please see the example:

**View**:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Events"))
{
   @Html.TextBox("name")
   <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

**Controller**:

```
public class EventsController: Controller
{
   public ActionResult Search(string name)
   {
      //some operations goes here

      return View(); //return some view to the user
   }
}
```

If you need to work with more complex types just lern how to use models in ASP.NET MVC. Here is short example:

**Razor**:

```
@model UserModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Events"))
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)
   <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

**Controller**:

```
public class EventsController: Controller
{
   public ActionResult Search(UserModel model)
   {
      //some operations goes here

      return View(); //return some view to the user
   }
}
```

**Model (C#)**:

```
public class UserModel
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```