# Using Ajax to trigger an Action Result c#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

Using the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#submit').click(function () {
            var companyId = $('#companyCoid').val();
            var erpKey = $('#erpKey').val();
            if (companyId == "" || erpKey == "") {
                alert("You have not entered enough information");
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    type:post,
                    url: '@Url.Action("ErpDocument")',
                    data: {
                        coid: companyId,
                        documentKey: erpKey
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

I am trying to trigger this action result which would navigate to a new view:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ErpDocument(string coid, string documentKey)
        {               
                var cview = new ConnectorViewModel();
                Stuff and things here....

            return View(cview);
        }
```

I am getting the information from a form above and the check for blank fields works just fine, however, the function in my controller is never hit.

---

**EDIT**: Reason it wasn't hitting the ActionResult was I had `post` and not `"POST"`, this now hits my method but does not display my new view.

Comment: I believe the rendered html of the view is going to be returned to your ajax call. It is up to you to do something with it.

Comment: Insted of -> url: @Url.Action("ErpDocument") Try this: url: 'yourPathToAction/ErpDocument',

Comment: @Jack Is there a better way to just grab the two values I want and call that action?

@ Örvar When the page renders that is what Url.Action actually returns, that is whats being called.

Comment: Why are using ajax if you just want to display that new view? If you want the rendered html on the current page you have to put it somewhere in the `success` callback of your ajax funciton. `$('#mydiv').html(dataFromAJAX);`

Comment: Yes this is a corner case, what is being returned has auto generated CSS that I want to maintain in a new view.  I have tried going to route that you displayed above, but that messes with all of the CSS on the page sadly.  Ultimately I just need a way to validate the user input isn't blank and then pass that information to the actionresult in my controller. I was thinking this could be done with an `Html.ActionLink` but not sure how to handle data validation.

Comment: In that case you can just submit the form like normal after you check the fields with javascript. This will "replace" the current view with the one returned from your actin result. https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Sorry I am not sure how to then pass those values to my actionresult, you cannot Call @Html.ActionLink/Result within Javascript. I may be miss understanding what you are getting at. Could you provide a little mark up in the form of an answer, if it fixes my issue I'll make sure to mark it as answer.

Comment: This post solved my issue: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873098/asp-net-mvc-4-razor-get-textbox-input-value

Using the same data validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the default contenttype is xml. you may need to add this

```
    contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

. I think that's what I've had to do before. Although unlikely, you may need to add a datatype as well.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/