# How to get textbox value from view to controller in mvc4 on submit button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

How to get the textbox value from view to controller in mvc4?If I using httppost method in controller the page cannot found error was came.

View

```
@model MVC_2.Models.FormModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DisplayForm";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("DisplayForm", "FormController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <form>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Empname)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Empname)
           @* @Html.Hidden("Emplname", Model.Empname)*@

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmpId)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmpId)
           @* @Html.Hidden("Emplid", Model.EmpId)*@

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmpDepartment)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmpDepartment)
           @* @Html.Hidden("Empldepart", Model.EmpDepartment)*@

            <input type="button" id="submitId" value="submit" />

        </div>
    </form>
}
```

model

```
   public class FormModel
    {
        public string _EmpName;
        public string _EmpId;
        public string _EmpDepartment;

        public string Empname
        {
            get {return _EmpName; }
            set { _EmpName = value; }
        }

        public string EmpId
        {
            get { return _EmpId;}
            set {_EmpId =value;}
        }

        public string EmpDepartment
        {
            get { return _EmpDepartment; }
            set { _EmpDepartment = value; }
        }
    }
```

controller

```
        public ActionResult DisplayForm()
        {
            FormModel frmmdl = new FormModel();
            frmmdl.Empname=**How to get the textbox value here from view on submitbutton click???**
        }
```

Comment: To say it simply, the model is sent as an argument to the method: `public ActionResult DisplayForm(FormModel frmmdl)` A fine tutorial for mvc: http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/

Comment: Use FormModel as parameter in your controller. Like DisplayForm(FormModel model)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22931220/how-to-get-textbox-value-from-view-to-controller-in-mvc4-on-submit-button-click/22931326#22931326

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC get textbox input value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873098/asp-net-mvc-get-textbox-input-value)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First you need to change your button type to **"submit"**. so your form values will be submitted to your Action method.

from:

```
<input type="button" id="submitId" value="submit" />
```

to:

```
<input type="submit" id="submitId" value="submit" />
```

Second you need to add your model as parameter in your Action method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DisplayForm(FormModel model)
    {
       var strname=model.Empname;
             return View();
    }
```

Third, If your Controller name is "FormController". you need to change the parameter of your Html.Beginform in your view to this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DisplayForm", "Form", FormMethod.Post))

    {
    //your fields
    }
```

P.S.
If your view is the same name as your Action method which is "DisplayForm" you don't need to add any parameter in the Html.BeginForm. just to make it simple. like so:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
//your fields
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have an `ActionResult` for the form post:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DisplayForm(FormModel formModel)
{
    //do stuff with the formModel
    frmmdl.Empname = formModel.Empname;
}
```

Look into [Model Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410405%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). Default model binding will take the data embedded in your posted form values and create an object from them.

Answer (score 2):

Let's implement simple ASP.NET MVC subscription form with email textbox.

### Model

The data from the form is mapped to this model

```
public class SubscribeModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

### View

View name should match controller method name.

```
@model App.Models.SubscribeModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Subscribe", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
    <button type="submit">Subscribe</button>
}
```

### Controller

Controller is responsible for request processing and returning proper response view.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Subscribe(SubscribeModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //TODO: SubscribeUser(model.Email);
        }

        return View("Index", model);
    }
}
```

Here is my project structure. Please notice, "Home" views folder matches HomeController name.

[image: ASP.NET MVC structure]

Answer (score 1):

You model will be posted as a object on the action and you can get it in action on post like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DisplayForm(FormModel model)
        {
            // do whatever needed
          string emp = model.EmpName; 
        }
```

it you are posting data always put **HttpPost** attribute on the action.

Your view also has mistakes, make it like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DisplayForm", "Form", FormMethod.Post))
{
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Empname)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Empname)
           @* @Html.Hidden("Emplname", Model.Empname)*@

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmpId)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmpId)
           @* @Html.Hidden("Emplid", Model.EmpId)*@

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmpDepartment)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmpDepartment)
           @* @Html.Hidden("Empldepart", Model.EmpDepartment)*@

            <input type="button" id="submitId" value="submit" />

        </div>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Model values from hidden field? I recommend the strongly typed approach shown below:

```
public ActionResult DisplayForm(string Emplname, string Emplid, string Empldepart)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this.

The first uses `TryUpdateModel`:

```
    public ActionResult DisplayForm()
    {
        FormModel frmmdl = new FormModel();
        TryUpdateModel (frmmdl);

        // Your model should now be populated
    }
```

The other, simpler, version is simply to have the model as a parameter on the `[HttpPost]` version of the action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DisplayForm(FormModel frmmdl)
    {
        // Your model should now be populated
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller like below.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DisplayForm(FormModel model)
{
   var Empname = model.Empname;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult DisplayForm(FormModel model)
 {
     FormModel frmmdl = new FormModel();
     frmmdl.Empname=**How to get the textbox value here from view on submitbutton //click???**
 }
```

model.Empname will have the value

Answer (score 0):

You need to have both Get and Post Methods:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DisplayForm()
    {
       FormModel model=new FormModel();
             return View(model);
    }
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DisplayForm(FormModel model)
    {
       var employeeName=model.Empname;
             return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DisplayForm(FormModel model)
{
    var value1 = model.EmpName;
}
```