# Asp.net MVC Get Textbox Value In View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So I have an inputbox

```
<input type='text' name='quantity' value='1'/>
```

How do I access the value of it?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add to cart", "AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", new { id = Model.ProductID, quantity = IWANTTHEVALUEHERE } "")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Since the value of `quantity` can be changed on the client, you need to build the query string using javascript (`@Html.ActionLink` is parsed on the server before its sent to the client)

Comment: And how do I pass the query string to Html.ActionLink? New to mvc.

Comment: You don't because `@Html.ActionLink` is generated at the server. That why you need to generate a `href` attribute using javascript/jquery and use `window.location.href = "...";` If you need an example let me know

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC get textbox input value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873098/asp-net-mvc-get-textbox-input-value)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input type='text' id='qty' name='quantity' value='1'/>

@Html.ActionLink("Add to cart", "AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", new { id = "link" })
```

and add have this in your javascript:

```
$('#link').click(function () {
  var id = '@Model.ProductID';
  var quantity = $('#qty').val(); 
  window.location = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")?id=' + id + '&quantity=' + quantity;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.ActionLink` generates the html for the link on the server before it is sent to the browser. Since the value of `quantity` can be changed in the browser, you need to use javascript/jquery to update the links `href` attribute.

View

```
<input type='text' id="quantity" name='quantity'> // give it an id
// no point adding route parameters yet since they will be changed on the client
@Html.ActionLink("Add to cart", "AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", null, new { id = "myLink" })
```

Script (make you you include the jquery.js file)

```
$('#myLink').click(function (e) {
  e.peventDefault(); // stop default redirect
  var id = '@Model.ProductID';
  var quantity = $('#quantity').val(); // get the quantity from the textbox
  var href = $(this).attr('href'); //  get current href value
  href = href + '?id=' + id + '&quantity=' + quantity; // update with parameters
  window.location.href = href; // redirect
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value sent to a controller's action like thi:

the Controller Action:

```
public class CartController {

   // controller action
   [HttpGet]
   public void addToCart(string item, int quantity)
   {
      return "Your cart now contains: " + quantity + " " + itemName;
      // You may do something else
   }
}
```

The View:

```
<form method="GET" action="/Cart/addToCart">
   <input type='text' name="item" value='apple'>
   <input type='text' name="quantity" value="1">
   <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
</form>
```

Output:

```
"Your cart now contains 1 apple."
```

The form will submit the data via GET to "/Cart/addToCart"
Your browser will link to something like: "http:1234//Cart/addToCart/?item=apple&quantity=1"