# Javascript in actionlink param

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want to add result of this function as param in

```
@Html.ActionLink("name","action",$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").map(function () {return this.name;}).get().join(",");)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You need to build the query string using javascript. `@Html.ActionLink` is parsed on the server before its sent to the client. [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290237/asp-net-mvc-get-textbox-value-in-view/26290691#26290691)

Answer (score 0):

You can not define in this way.

Use as

```
 ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, Object)
 @Html.ActionLink("name","action",new{object as you want};)
```

[**Reference**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: So there is no way to run this code and get string as param?