# using razor form and model values instead of current js object

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm following js snippet to grab value dynamic number of input elements. I then use that values as a property inside js object which I later sent to mvc controller.

Since I already using Model inside razor which already has necessary properties to send to the mvc controller I wonder how can I grab those dynamic input elements values without using javascript object.

```
var myArr= [];
for (var i = 1; true; i++) {
    var pTxtBox = $('#PCaption' + i);
    var nTxtBox = $('#PWinners' + i);

    if ((pTxtBox).length) {
        var myObj = {};
        myObj.Name = pTxtBox.val();
        myObj.NWinners = nTxtBox.val();
        myArr.push(myObj);
    } else {
             break;
           }
    }
```

Comment: The model contains the initial values you send to the view, not the edited properties.

Comment: [ASP.NET MVC get textbox input value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873098/asp-net-mvc-get-textbox-input-value)

Answer (score 0):

When you render a page in MVC, The model is populated with whatever you specifically pass into the view. As MVC isn't coupled with the server. The only time the model re-binds is when there is a post back, then it goes through the input fields with the correct 'name' attribute and binds them into the model expected into the HTTPPOST method in the controller.

You will not be able to dynamically get a textboxes value on the client side using razor, Youll have to get the element by id or class, just as you are doing here.