# How to use defaultModelBinder in order to bind my view to my model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass an object `Guy` to my controller through my view and I am not sure how to do it. 
I tried to do a @Model Guy in my view, but that didn't work, so I am out of ideas how to pass an object to my Create method, and not just some variables, since i don't want to build this object in the method.
From what I understood from my research i have to use the defauldModelBinder in order to bind my model to the view, but it's not really clear to me how to do that as I am a complete novice.
Any tips? I am sorry if my question is too basic.

My view currently looks like this :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Guys", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="text" name="id" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="title" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="content" value="" />
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

And my controller like this :

```
static List<Guy> Guys = new List<Guy> { new Guy(1,"phd","hi1"), new Guy(2, "proff", "hi2!"), new Guy(3, "proff.asst.", "hi3") };


public ActionResult Create(Guy obj)
        {

           Guys.Add(obj);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Guys");
        }
```

And my model :

```
 public class Guy
{
    public int GuyId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }


    public Guy(int GuyId, string Title, string Content)
    {
        this.GuyId = GuyId;
        this.Title = Title;
        this.Content = Content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use same model names in your text field names, try to match the cases in your text field names, it should work

Comment: Even if i don't have @Model Guy ?  Because I can't add this for some reason.

Comment: If you strongly type your view with @model Guy (at the top of your view), you can then use HTML helpers. The approach you are using should work too but its better to have a strongly typed view and use HTML helpers for model binding

Comment: See this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873098/asp-net-mvc-get-textbox-input-value

Comment: I tried the same thing earlier and i get Guy underlined in red (in @model Guy) and a error "the type or namespace name "Guy" could not be found".

Comment: You have to add a reference to Guy object on top. Try using the complete namespace the Guy is in. Like @model namespace.Guy

Comment: Partly worked, but when i press the submit button it gives me : No parameterless constructor defined for this object. I didn't really change my Create(), which already has a Guy parameter, so i dunno why i get this

Comment: Try to add a parameterless constructor in your Guy.cs

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth to define a default constructor in the model otherwise you might get an error. Apart from that your code seems to work.

Here is the code with which I have tried:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(Guys.First());
    }


static List<Guy> Guys = new List<Guy> { new Guy(1, "phd", "hi1"), new Guy(2,     "proff", "hi2!"), new Guy(3, "proff.asst.", "hi3") };

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Guy obj)
{

    Guys.Add(obj);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Guys");
}}
```

The class Guy:

```
  public class Guy
{
    public int GuyId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public Guy()
    {

    }

    public Guy(int GuyId, string Title, string Content)
    {
        this.GuyId = GuyId;
        this.Title = Title;
        this.Content = Content;
    }
}
```

and the View:

```html
@model Models.Guy


@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="text" name="GuyId" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="title" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="content" value="" />
    <input type="submit" />
}
```