# How to get the value of an input button in an ASP.NET Core MVC controller?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How to get the value of an input button in an ASP.NET Core MVC controller?

This is my html code in the view

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="GetstartTime" method="post" id="TableF">
            <input id="1" name="f1" form="TableF" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="12:00 PM"/>
            <input id="2" name="f2" form="TableF" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="2:00 PM"/>
            <input id="3" name="f3" form="TableF" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="3:00 PM"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `this.Request.Form["f0"]` should do fine. Assuming you have a `form` there.

Comment: You could use BeginForm like this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873098/asp-net-mvc-get-textbox-input-value

Comment: @WiktorZychla we have multi buttons so i don't know which id will be come to the controller

Comment: @MinaEssam: This still is not clear enough. Try to expand your example to show what your actual issue really is. At the moment, your `html` doesn't even have any `form`, it doesn't make much sense to reason about what happens at the server.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Please look to my update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in the razor :

```
<form asp-controller="Controller" asp-action="PostData">
<input  id="f0"  name="f0" form="TableF" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="12:00 PM"/>
</form>
```

in the controller :

```
 [HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostData(string f0)
{
    var buttonvalue =f0;
}
```