# How to retrieve input's value from a textbox

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, forms

I'm learning to develop a webapp using .net and I'm having a problem in retrieving the value from an `<input>`

```
 Size:
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetList", "User", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.PageSize)
    
    
    <input type="submit" value="Invia" />
}
```

I want to retrieve the value posted and then use it as a parameter in the url but all I try isn't working and all this is frustrating me a lot, thanks for the help.

Comment: You'll have to state the problem more clearly and with more detail. When you debug the controller what do you experience? What is the code of the controller?

Comment: Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873098/asp-net-mvc-get-textbox-input-value

Answer (score 0):

In your Post method in the Controller, define an input variable with the same datatype of the model that you are using in the view. Then you will be able to get the values that you have on the screen.

What happens is that when the submit button is pressed, all the input values will be submitted to Controller's post method.

Supposing that your model's datatype is "User", the Controller's Post method should look like the below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetList(User model)
{
    int pageSize = model.PageSize;
    ...
    return View();
}
```